# Usage of Replace within a Function

Tags: sql-server

I have a function that upper cases the first character of a column:

```
CREATE or alter FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital]
   (@Text                      VARCHAR(5000)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(5000) 
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Index                 INT;
DECLARE @FirstChar             CHAR(1);
DECLARE @LastChar              CHAR(1);
DECLARE @String                VARCHAR(5000);
SET @String = LOWER(@Text);
SET @Index = 1;
WHILE @Index <= LEN(@Text)
    BEGIN
        SET @FirstChar = SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index, 1);
        SET @LastChar = CASE
                            WHEN @Index = 1
                            THEN ' '
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index - 1, 1)
                        END;
        IF @LastChar IN(' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(', '#', '*', '$', '@')
            BEGIN
                IF @FirstChar != ''''
                   OR UPPER(@FirstChar) != 'S'
                    SET @String = STUFF(@String, @Index, 1, UPPER(@FirstChar));
        END;
        SET @Index = @Index + 1;

    END;
        RETURN @String;
        END;
go
```

Given this data: `Select [dbo].[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital] ('User_id')`
it produces this result:

```
(No column name)
User_Id
```

I would like to convert the column name to Camel Case: i.e: the result should be: `UserId`

I tried changing the Function:

```
CREATE or alter FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital]
   (@Text                      VARCHAR(5000)) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(5000) 
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @Index                 INT;
DECLARE @FirstChar             CHAR(1);
DECLARE @LastChar              CHAR(1);
DECLARE @String                VARCHAR(5000);
SET @String = LOWER(@Text);
SET @Index = 1;
WHILE @Index <= LEN(@Text)
    BEGIN
        SET @FirstChar = SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index, 1);
        SET @LastChar = CASE
                            WHEN @Index = 1
                            THEN ' '
                            ELSE SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index - 1, 1)
                        END;
        IF @LastChar IN(' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(', '#', '*', '$', '@')
            BEGIN
                IF @FirstChar != ''''
                   OR UPPER(@FirstChar) != 'S'
                    SET @String = STUFF(@String, @Index, 1, UPPER(@FirstChar));
        END;
        SET @Index = @Index + 1;

        REPLACE(String,'_','');
    END;
        RETURN @String;
        END;
go
```

but it gives me this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ConvertFirstLetterinCapital, Line 28 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'REPLACE'.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you want `set @String = REPLACE(@String,'_','');`

Comment: Also, put the REPLACE out of the WHILE loop.

Comment: You can just change the last RETURN @String to RETURN REPLACE(@String,'_','');

Answer (score 0):

As Dale said, you need to change `REPLACE(String,'_','');` to `SET @String = REPLACE(@String,'_','');`

However, I changed that in your code and ran it with `SELECT dbo.[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital]('user_id')` which returned an erroneous value of `UseriI`

I have rewritten the function as below. This removes any character defined as a split character in the `PATINDEX` and changes the following character to upper case.

```
CREATE or ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital]
(
    @Text VARCHAR(5000)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(5000) 
AS 
BEGIN
    -- first character to upper
    DECLARE @FirstChar CHAR(1) = SUBSTRING(@Text,1,1)
    SET @Text = STUFF(@Text,1,1,UPPER(@FirstChar))

    -- Camel case
    DECLARE @NextWordStartChar CHAR(1)
    DECLARE @NextSplitCharPos INT

    -- while we have splitting characters
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[_,/]%',@Text) > 0
    BEGIN
        -- remove the splitting character and set the next character to uppercase
        SET @NextSplitCharPos = PATINDEX('%[_,/]%',@Text) -- need to put all your split characters in the Charindex
        SET @NextWordStartChar = UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Text, @NextSplitCharPos +1,1))
        SET @Text = STUFF(@text, @NextSplitCharPos,1,'')
        SET @Text = STUFF(@text,@NextSplitCharPos,1,@NextWordStartChar)
    END
    RETURN @Text
END
```

Now running

`SELECT dbo.[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital]('user_id')` returns `UserId`

The function also deals with multiple split characters so

`SELECT dbo.[ConvertFirstLetterinCapital]('user_id/number')` returns `UserIdNumber`